# How to install docker correctly in ubuntu 22.04 is it possible at this time?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am following the docker installation tutorial in ubuntu: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/ubuntu/

And when I try this step: `sudo apt install ./docker-desktop-4.8.1-amd64.deb` I am getting the next error: E: `Unsupported file ./docker-desktop-4.8.1-amd64.deb given on commandline`

Not sure what that means or if I am missing something.

```
E: Unsupported file ./docker-desktop-4.8.1-amd64.deb given on commandline
```

I also tried with:

```
curl https://desktop-stage.docker.com/linux/main/amd64/74134/docker-desktop.deb --output docker-desktop.deb
sudo apt install ./docker-desktop.deb
```

And got the error:

```
E: Invalid archive signature
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar{.zst,.lz4,.gz,.xz,.bz2,.lzma,}
E: Could not read meta data from /home/rodolfo/docker-desktop.deb
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What CPU architecture are you on? Docs say "Docker Desktop is supported on x86_64 (or amd64) architecture."

Comment: My architecture is x86_64, is there any option for this architecture?

Comment: x86_64 should be fine

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, but I am getting this weird error, running the docker installation command

Comment: Can you do a `cat ./docker-desktop.deb`? Probably you did not download the deb file but an error message.

Comment: which Ubuntu version you have ?

Comment: I am now stuck in the same problem, I transferred a file
docker-desktop-4.8.1-amd64.deb
from this path:
/home/sahar/snap/chromium
to home
This error is gone but there is another error that I solve now

Comment: I have ubuntu 22.04, finally I installed docker Engine, waiting for a solution to install docker desktop

Answer (score 3):

According to official documentation, and the steps I followed to install docker in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

1. Visit the following site https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
2. Scroll down until you find the **Install using the convenience script** section.
3. You will find the following commands:

> $ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
>
> $ DRY_RUN=1 sh ./get-docker.sh

- the first command will install a shell script with the all needed commands and the other will run this shell script.

4. You can test the installation by running these commands

> $ sudo docker --version
>
> $ sudo docker info

5. If it looks fine, you now have docker in your machine.
6. Optional step is to download docker desktop for Ubuntu 22.04
   https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/

- MAKE SURE You already installed docker engine before installing docker desktop for Ubuntu

Comment: This saved me, because installing the docker desktop .deb just resulted in an unhelpful "Dependency resolution failed" which I didn't find anything about. So I hope Google will index this and help the next lost soul.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the DEB file to HOME folder or Change the directory in terminal to the folder where the file is downloaded

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem and the solution was to go to the folder root that I downloaded the deb file in it wish is Downloads for me and I rerun the commend

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being Ubuntu 22.04 was installed with wsl version 1.

`wsl -l -v`

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
  Ubuntu-22.04           Running         1
```

`wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2`